# Regex - Can quantifier skip certain range?

Tags: regex

I have a simple regex like this `[0-9a-zA-Z]{32,45}` that matches 0-9,a-z,A-Z 32 to 45 times. Is there a way I can have the regex skip a certain range? For example, I don't want to match if there are 40 characters.

Comment: use an alteration `|` with 2 ranges and skip 40 `\b(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]{32,39}|[0-9a-zA-Z]{41,45})\b`

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that would be

```
\b[0-9a-zA-Z]{32,39}+(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]{2,6})?\b
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/gyQTXG/1). You match 32 to 39 occurrences possessively, then an optional occurrence of 2 to 6 repetitions of the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Another way could be using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|` repeating the character class either 41-45 times or 32-39 times.

You could prepend and append a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` to the pattern.

```
\b(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]{41,45}|[0-9a-zA-Z]{32,39})\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sQANje/1)